# How to give an app permission to see a subset of contacts

Tags: contacts, permissions, privacy

Some apps require access to my contacts list in order to function (e.g. WhatsApp). I am concerned about the privacy implications of giving permission to apps to see my entire contacts list, which may include private information that is not relevant to chat apps (e.g. birth dates, home addresses, personal notes, etc.). Is there a way to limit the contacts that an app can see? I only want to expose a subset of my contacts list to such apps.

Comment: What you want is not possible on stock devices.

Comment: @Robert Is it possible if I have superuser privileges on my phone?

Comment: ON a rooted phone this is possible but very complicated e.g. using [Ed]Xposed + XPrivacyLua. But both technologies are more or less EOL, and have many disadvantages so I would not recommend it.